# I want to Put extra information at realtime database node created using geofire (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I want to put extra data at  node in database this node is created using geofire and when i try to put this information is appear at database then hide like below,

```
availableDrivers
   3gDKSbnMEBYZsZDwL6lmiQerP9P2
       g: 
         "stq5ncg7kr"
       l
        0: 30.0688058
        1: 31.2387825
```

I want to add extra information like

```
availableDrivers
   3gDKSbnMEBYZsZDwL6lmiQerP9P2
       g: 
         "stq5ncg7kr"
       l
        0: 30.0688058
        1: 31.2387825
      name: bishoy
      age: 24
```

they added but then hide or removed, below my code.

main

```
DatabaseReference adminRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("admin");
DatabaseReference driversRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers");
DatabaseReference newRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Request");
DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers").child(currentfirebaseUser!.uid).child("newRide");
DatabaseReference availableDriver = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("availableDrivers").child(currentfirebaseUser!.uid);
```

function that generate availabledriver and I put my extra information their

```
 void makeDriverOnlineNow() async
  {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    Map<String, dynamic> driverMap = {
      "name" : driversInformation!.name,
      "phone" : driversInformation!.phone,
    };

    Geofire.initialize("availableDrivers");
    Geofire.setLocation(currentfirebaseUser!.uid, currentPosition!.latitude, currentPosition!.longitude);
    await availableDriver.update(driverMap);

    rideRequestRef.set("searching");
    rideRequestRef.onValue.listen((event) {

    });
  }

void getLocationLiveUpdates()
  {
    homeTabPageStreamSubscription = Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position position)
    {
      currentPosition = position;
      if(isDriverAvailable == true)
      {
        Geofire.setLocation(currentfirebaseUser!.uid, position.latitude, position.longitude);
      }
      LatLng latLng = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      newcontrollerGoogleMap!.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(latLng));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible in the `flutter_geofire` to add your own data to the node that it manages. Of the GeoFire implementations that Firebase itself delivers only the Android library allows you to add your own data to the geolocation node, and I'll admit to not being a big fan of it.

To keep your own data, set up you database like this:

```
driverLocations: {
  // geolocation data, managed by geofire
  "3gDKSbnMEBYZsZDwL6lmiQerP9P2": {
    "g": "stq5ncg7kr",
    "l": [30.0688058, 31.2387825]
  }
},
drivers: {
  // driver properties, managed by you
  "3gDKSbnMEBYZsZDwL6lmiQerP9P2": {
    name: "bishoy",
    age: 24
  }
  }
}
```

Now it is clear what data is managed by whom, and you'll typically only access the `driverLocations` data through GeoFire. Once you get the key of a driver from GeoFire, you can look up their properties from `/drivers/$key`. Doing this for multiple drivers is not as slow as you may initially expect, because [Firebase pipelines the requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) over a single WebSocket connection.

Comment: First thnq for your help and your time but my data now at database like you write, and I want to make a list from availabledrivers and get some information from driver  node but i can't do this because that i want put this data at available because it's easy to make a list from available driver

Comment: A client-side join is indeed more finicky in code, so if you're having trouble making that work I recommend creating a question showing [where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).